# Replacing wkhtmltopdf 0.11rc-1 with 0.12 on Ubuntu x64 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I have problem with replacing `wkhtmltopdf` with new one on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Old version was on this location : `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` and it was working ok but with old bugs. I have downloaded new version for x64 linux from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkhtmltopdf/files/0.12.1-dev/ .
After download and unpacking tar, I copy all folders/files to `/usr/local/`

```
|-- bin
|   |-- wkhtmltoimage
|   `-- wkhtmltopdf
|-- include
|   `-- wkhtmltox
|       |-- dllbegin.inc
|       |-- dllend.inc
|       |-- image.h
|       `-- pdf.h
`-- lib
    |-- libwkhtmltox.so.0 -> libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1
    |-- libwkhtmltox.so.0.12 -> libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1
    `-- libwkhtmltox.so.0.12.1
```

After all that when I run `wkhtmltopdf` I get this message :

```
wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where can I find that lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, there was missing this package : `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`. Solved by :

> sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0

Comment: apt-get is misspelled.

Comment: Great. Also I had to install package `libxrender1` to fix the following error: `wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @luissquall yes, libxrender is required. I have that from previous version. This tutorial that I have been using for wkhtmltopdf earlier [link](http://blog.hemantthorat.com/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-12-04/) (#wget... part in my case)